# Git clone is denied in cygwin but not in cmd

Tags: git, cygwin, command-prompt

In Cygwin:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:xxx/dotfiles.git
Cloning into 'dotfiles'...    
/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/dotfiles/.git/refs: Permission denied
```

But then when I tried the same command in command prompt, it worked fine and the repo was cloned.

Why is there a permissions error when creating that directory?
This is most likely a local problem with cygwin.

Edit: So I'm able to clone the repo after starting cygwin as administrator in Windows.

Comment: Make sure they both are using the same ssh key or use the https repository uri

Comment: The problem here is on the local side, not on the remote. Looks like the Cygwin system doesn't have the right perms on that directory.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Yes, that's what I was thinking too, but I don't understand why. How would I give it the permissions?

Comment: Have you started cygwin in admin mode?

Comment: Could you try a `ls -la /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/dotfiles` to show us the permissions for that folder. Do a `echo $USER` too. To get the user of the console.

Comment: @crea1 So after starting cygwin in admin mode, I'm able to properly clone it

Comment: @AnimiVulpis I wouldn't be able to ls the dotfiles folder because it doesn't exist yet as I can't clone it. 
Echoing the USER prints out my username

Comment: Okay. So maybe cygwin has not the correct permission to create the folder inside the `Users/xxx/` folder. Can you create it manually via cygwin?

Comment: Yes, I can create it manually. And yes, it looks like you're right. I can git clone in any folders not in c/Users/xxx/

Answer (score 0):

`/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx` is the place for windows Home User.
It has tons of specific ACL constrains.

Make a directory on the traditional `/home/xxx` or in a dedicate directory under cygwin root; I created a `/pub` for all my building activity on cygwin.